# ECONNREFUSED socket.io GRITS google game

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to set up the Google HTML 5 "Grits" on Mac OS X.

http://code.google.com/p/gritsgame/wiki/DeveloperSetUp

When I get to [Actually run locally](http://code.google.com/p/gritsgame/wiki/DeveloperSetUp#Actually_running_locally) I'm getting this error:

```
$ sudo node games-server/main.js $*
   info  - socket.io started
SERVERID: nKmXj1MfcULEx31vTlBtmz+u
checkConnection: POST http://localhost:9100/register-controller -> FAILED due to Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
Will call checkConnection again in 3.2 seconds
```

I'm new to node, is there something I need to do to start the server first before I run this command?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

You need to start app engine first:

```
dev_appserver.py --skip_sdk_update_check --backends . $*
```

Then you can run the node command

```
node games-server/main.js $*
```

(I'm not sure why the wiki has them in the opposite order.)